# Rails - Getting the ID of the Wrong Model in Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

In my Rails 3.2 app, I have `User`, `Comment`, and `Article` models.  In a view I'm trying to show all of a User's comments ordered by the article date (comments belong to articles).  The problem is that in my view, when I try to retrieve the comment id, I get the article id.

```
***Models***
# user.rb
has_many :comments

# comment.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :article

scope :by_article_date,
select("*, articles.date as article_date").
joins(:article).
order("article_date DESC")

# article.rb
has_many :comments


# users_controller
def comments      
  @user = current_user
  @comments = @user.comments.by_article_date
end


# comments.html.erb
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= comment.id %> # shows the article id, but should be comment.id
  <%= comment.article.id %> # shows article id correctly
<% end %>
```

Can someone please help me figure out what's going on?

Comment: Can you try debugging your instance variable `@comments` by calling `@comments.first.class`? Then you'll be able to see if you're getting a collection of comments or articles.

Comment: When I put <%= @comments.first.class %> it returns `Comment`

Comment: Hmm, the plot thickens. Can you tell us exactly how you figured out it's returning the article id instead of the comment id?

Comment: I first figured it out because I had <%= link_to "Edit Comment", edit_comment(comment) %> in the view and it was pointing to a non-existent record, so I realized it was using the Article id.  The view works if I set `@comments = @user.comments` in the controller, but it doesn't sort by Article.date if I do that

Comment: Try this in your scope: `scope :by_article_date, -> { joins(:article).order("articles.article_date DESC") }`

Comment: I get `Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'articles.article_date' in 'order clause'`

Comment: My bad, it should be `articles.date`

Comment: Nice! Let me add that as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your scope:

```
scope :by_article_date, -> { joins(:article).order("articles.date DESC") }
```